# How to use SMS service in BB10 using BB10 webworks?

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I am trying to use SMS service in BB10 through webworks.But I always get an error "Cannot read property 'sms' of undefined" .The code I am using is :

Javascript :

```
blackberry.message.sms.send('hello world', '9999999999');
```

Config file :

```
<feature id="blackberry.message.sms" />
```

Is there any way to use the SMS service ?

Comment: Hi Arpit, Have you found any solution? because i have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: My bad.. there is on SMS API just yet.  Generally if you get an error stating blackberry is not defined, and it is an API that's available, this will help you troubleshoot though.. :)

--

Looks like the 'blackberry' namespace is undefined?  Are you loading the webworks.js file properly, and waiting for it to have initialized before you try to access the API?

You include the webworks.js file like so in the index html file for your app..

```
<script src="local:///chrome/webworks.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, you need to have something similar to this (also in the index) which triggers after the 'webworksready' event fires

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.addEventListener("webworksready", function(){

   // webworks is now ready, do cool stuff here

});
</script>
```

Also, check-out our Getting Started material if you wish: http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/getting_started_with_bb10_ww_sdk_2007056_11.html

Comment: Hi chadtatro thanks. Can you please tell me how to launch app in BB10 device.I am getting error 22.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no SMS extension for webworks on BB10

Answer (score 0):

in your config.xml file add this:

```
<feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke.card" />
```

then use this invocation function in your script file:

```
    doSMSinvokation = function(ppsEncode) {
    blackberry.invoke.invoke({
        target: "sys.pim.text_messaging.composer",
        action: "bb.action.COMPOSE",
        data: ppsEncode({"to":["55555"], "body":"body of SMS", "send":"false"})},
    function(successEvt) {
        alert("Success");
    },
            function(errorEvt) {
                alert("error");
            }
    );
    var ppsEncode = function(obj) {
            var data = '', name, value;
            for (name in obj) {
                data += name + ':';
                value = obj[name];
                if (typeof value === 'string') {
                    data += ':' + value;
                }
                else if (typeof value === 'number') {
                    data += 'n:' + value;
                }
                else if (typeof value === 'boolean') {
                    data += 'b:' + value;
                }
                else if (typeof value === 'object') {
                    data += 'json:' + JSON.stringify(value);
                }
                data += '\n';
            }
            return data;
        }
        doSMSinvokation(ppsEncode);
```

My referance from [Blackberry](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/text_messages.html) itself